# Why getStatickProps return undefine for commerce js?

Tags: next.js, commerce

I am trying Commerce js with NextJS in the commerce.js file everything works well and I have all the return data. But when I import the data from commerce.js file getStaticProps return undefine

```
import { client } from '../utils/commerce'

const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const commerce = client
    const { data } = await commerce.products.list()

    return {
        props: {
            products: data
        }
    }
}

export default function Home({ products }) {
  
    console.log(products)

    return (
        <> <div> Hello </div> </>
    ) 
}
```

The **console.log(products)** return undefine
Can someone help me understand the problem, please?

**Commerce.js file**

```
import Commerce from '@chec/commerce.js'

export const client = new Commerce(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CHEC_PUBLIC_API_KEY, true)
```

Comment: can you provide some code from your commerce file please? So I can see how the imported {client} is structured

Comment: Hi Andrew, I just have the following code in the commerce.js file:

import Commerce from '@chec/commerce.js'

export const client = new Commerce(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CHEC_PUBLIC_API_KEY, true)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I ask myself why we have to make mistakes while coding, LOL! Gyus I just forget to export the getStaticProps method. It is nonsense, really.